# What does solana-test-validator do on the background?

Tags: blockchain, solana

When run `solana-test-validator` it begins a new process with the following output:

```
Ledger location: test-ledger
Log: test-ledger/validator.log
Identity: 4876NsAf6yH8c7uPXybETZPit142i2QhR7tfSoTPYjHf
Genesis Hash: CrqeHuGVmgHL54Sri7dEm2aCRLFopJrTHoQBYe6ciF7N
Version: 1.8.17
Shred Version: 28931
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
⠄ 01:44:22 | Processed Slot: 48335 | Confirmed Slot: 48335 | Finalized Slot: 483
```

I understand:

- what consensus alg or leader election is,
- how blocks are ended up in a block chain
- what a Solana validator is

I've also read Solana cluster, validator, slot, epochs docs.
It says

```
Slot: The period of time for which each leader ingests transactions and produces a block.
```

Could someone explain what happens when we run `solana-test-validator`? In particular, does it produce blocks/ledger entries? From what it continuously displays
`⠄ 01:44:22 | Processed Slot: 48335 | Confirmed Slot: 48335 | Finalized Slot: 483`
it seems to be producing new blocks? If so, why do we need those ledger entries? After all nothing happens locally on my cluster (no transactions, not sol transfer....).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To your first question the answer is Yes.

To your second question, the test-validator ***is a ledger node*** and as such, just like devnet/testnet/mainnet-beta, there is the temporal record (block) as you progress through time, whether there was something done or not.

##### Edits:

When you start and run `solana-test-validator` for the first time it will create a default ledger called `test-ledger` in the directory where you started it from.

If you start the test validator again, in the same location, it will open the existing ledger. Over time the ledger may become quite large.

If you want to start with a clean ledger, you can either:

1. `rm -rf test-ledger` or...
2. `solana-test-validator --reset`

Comment: Do you mean that the cluster (nodes) has to generate ledger entries because of the blockchain design (PoH, etc)? If so, it must store those entries locally on my HD, right?

Comment: Correct, that is what you are seeing

Comment: @Frnak-c How can I remove entries from my HD? You wouldn't want it to fill your HD with unnecessary entries, would you? Or is blockchain automatically cleaned when we stop it? But accounts I created are still there even after I stop local solana.

Comment: I added an edit that should give you control over HD space.